# Unable to compare lists and array in scala

Tags: scala

My problem statement is as below:

1) I have a path till a folder. I have to traverse using that path. Check whether there are any subfolders and files in that path. If yes, match the contents of the folder(Lists) with the array. If it matches take it as a new path.

2) Using new path. List down the files in that path.

I am able to do everything except comparing `lists` and `array`. Below is my code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import java.io.File

class ListingDirectories {
  def getListOfDirectories(dir: String): List[File] = {
    val d = new File(dir)
    if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
      d.listFiles().filter(_.isDirectory()).toList
    } else {
      List[File]()
    }
  }
  def getListOfFiles(dir: String): List[File] = {
    val d = new File(dir)
    if (d.exists && d.isDirectory()) {
      d.listFiles().filter(_.isFile()).toList
    } else {
      List[File]()
    }
  }
}

object FirstSample {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val ld = new ListingDirectories()
    val directoriesList = ld.getListOfDirectories("C:/Users/Siddheshk2/Desktop/CENSUS").toList
    println(directoriesList + "\n")
    val directoriesListReplaced = directoriesList.toString().replace("//", "/")
    // println(directoriesListReplaced.indexOf("C:/Users/Siddheshk2/Desktop/CENSUS/SAMPLE"))

    var finalString = ""
    var s = Array("C:/Users/Siddheshk2/Desktop/CENSUS/SAMPLE")
    for (x <- s) {
      if (x.equals(directoriesListReplaced)) {
        finalString = s(0)

      } else {
        println("No matching strings")
      }
    }
    val filesList = ld.getListOfFiles(finalString)
    println(filesList.toString())

  }
}
```

I just need to compare the values from the list and array and take it as a new path in `finalString` variable in order to pass in the next method which is `getListOfFiles`.  I figured out since I am returning `List[file]` in methods I am not able to access the elements inside it. Can anyone help me to understand where am I going wrong?  TIA

Comment: could you share the Error stack-trace that you have encountered?

Comment: There is no error. Code works fine but goes in to the else loop. Nothing else.

Comment: The code works as is for me too. does the folder **SAMPLE** exists inside **CENSUS**?

Comment: Yes, there are 3 folders inside CENSUS named SAMPLE,SAMPLE1,SAMPLE2. I have to compare values which is in array (its the value which I want to compare ) and file list values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of struggle, I solved it using below code:

```
import java.io.File
object PlayingWithLists {
  def main(ar: Array[String]) {
    var s = "C:/Users/Siddheshk2/Desktop/CENSUS/SAMPLE2"
    var finalValue = ""
    var valuesReplaced = ""
    var filePath = ""
    for (file <- new File("C:/Users/Siddheshk2/Desktop/CENSUS").listFiles) {
      valuesReplaced = file.toString.replace("\\", "/")

      if (valuesReplaced.contains(s.trim)) {
        finalValue = file.toString
      } else {

      }
    }
    for (file <- new File(finalValue).listFiles) {
      filePath = file.toString.trim
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `directoriesListReplaced` will be a string which looks like `"List(C:/Users/Siddheshk2/Desktop/CENSUS/SAMPLE,C:/Users/Siddheshk2/Desktop/CENSUS/SAMPLE1,C:/Users/Siddheshk2/Desktop/CENSUS/SAMPLE2)"` and `s` won't equal it. It isn't at all clear what you want to do with `directoriesListReplaced`; maybe it should just be

```
for (x <- s) {
  if (directoriesList.contains(x)) {
    ...
  } else {
    println("No matching strings")
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited your code according to mine and it gives me  only 'C' value when I try to print finalString var. So, it gives value at first index

Comment: That's what `s(0)` does, yes (or `x(0)` in the case of your edit): first character of the string. You just want `finalString = x` (and change the condition).

Comment: It was not working because of the return type in the methods. So, I simplified it and got the results